# Работа с данными после получения данных (с использованием API)

Tags: java, android, api, int

Я получил данные с использованием API в таком формате main.getString("pressure"), мне приходит значение (числовое) не в той единице измерения, которая мне нужна (например мне приходит 1000, а надо 1000/10 и в итоге 100). Как мне сделать так, чтобы я полученное значение, мог делить, умножать и проводить другие арифметические действия?

Comment: Наверное можно `main.getInt("pressure")` или `Integer.parseInt(main.getString("pressure"))`

Answer (score 0):

Похоже речь о том, как распарсить строку в число, тогда вам помогут методы вида Integer.valueOf(string) и т.п. Такие же методы есть во Float и других типах